# Problem with scp syntax

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote-access, scp

I am trying to copy a .tar archive from remote server to my pc.

Directory of the archive that I want to copy:

```
canserhan@embserv:~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar
```

Destination:

```
serhan@serhan-Lenovo-B560:~/Documents$
```

I connect to remote server and use the command:

```
canserhan@embserv:~/tar_files$ scp canserhan@embserv:~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar serhan@serhan-Lenovo-B560:~Documents$
Password:
ssh: serhan-Lenovo-B560: Name or service not known
lost connection
canserhan@embserv:~/tar_files$
```

There must be something wrong with the scp syntax I am using. However I could not figure it out. Could you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add serhan-Lenovo-B560 as a hostname?

Comment: Pleas provide the output of `ssh serhan@serhan-Lenovo-B560`. I think there is a wrong `$` at the end of the line, but I don't think that this causes the error message.

Comment: @lumbric I tried it from a different PC and here is the output:

canserhan@ubuntu:~$ ssh canserhan@ubuntu

canserhan@ubuntu's password: 

Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

Comment: Ok, that means the SSH connection seems to be ok. I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule if you wanna send something to the remote server via scp:

```
scp some_files.tar user@remoteHost:
scp some_files.tar user@remoteHost:Documents/newname.tar
```

But if you wanna download something:

```
scp user@remoteHost:Documents/foo.tar ~/Desktop
scp user@remoteHost:/any/other/dir/foo.tar .
```

Answer (score 1):

From the scp man page:

> ```
>  -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local
>          host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between
>          the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the
>          progress meter.
> ```

I'd suggest that the problem is that your machine `embserv` cannot "see" your other machine `serhan-Lenovo-B560`, or, if it can, it can't resolve the name.

When you invoke scp with two remote machines, what it actually tries to do is something *like* this:

```
ssh canserhan@embserv "scp ~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar serhan@serhan-Lenovo-B560:~Documents$"
```

That's a Good Thing as it means the copy will be more efficient, but it requires that scp from machine A to machine B works, which it won't always.

If that is the problem, you can solve it by using `-3`, or by passing the numeric IP address of `serhan-Lenovo-B560` (if the name is the problem), or by fixing your ssh setup on `embserv` so that it can reach `serhan-Lenovo-B560`.

**EDIT:**

So, try this:

```
scp canserhan@embserv:~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar serhan@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:~Documents$
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx` is your server's IP address.

or, if that fails, this should definitely work, but will run more slowly:

```
scp -3 canserhan@embserv:~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar serhan@serhan-Lenovo-B560:~Documents$
```

By the way, `~Documents$` also looks wrong. Are you sure it shouldn't be `~/Documents` ?

Comment: I tried to pass the numeric IP address as follows (again I think I did something wrong with the syntax): canserhan@embserv:~$ scp ~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar 2xx.1xx.1x.8x  However, it created a directory named 2xx.1xx.1x.8x and copied ~/tar... to that directory. But when I did ls 2xx.1xx.1x.8x it said no such directory and also it let me delete that directory. I did not understand anything. If that directory have never existed then how come I could delete it? Was is something like a temp?

 Also I could not solve my problem by using -3. How can I fix my ssh setup on embserv?

Comment: If you put a colon `:` on the end then `scp` thinks it's a machine name. If you don't then it assumes it's a file name. So, `scp ~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar 2xx.1xx.1x.8x` is exactly the same as if you had used `cp`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: +1 for the -3 bit. I could ssh into a machine but scp was giving "Could not resolve hostname xxx: Name or service not known". Using the -3 option fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command:

```
scp ~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar serhan@serhan-Lenovo-B560:~/Documents/
```

`embserv` is your local machine. If you write `scp server1:/path/to/file server2:/path/to/second/file` this instructs `scp` to copy a file from one server to a second server. If you want to copy a local file to a server or the other way round just skip the colons `:` and the machine name. In additon `~` has to be followed by a slash in your case. `~` translates to `/home/username/`.

Comment: The command ending of **`user@hostname:~/Documents/`** is the same as **`user@hostname:Documents/`**. *The default destination path is **/home/<user>/**.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you don't have a DNS at your network..
It looks as if though it cannot resolve your name `serhan-Lenovo-B560`

You can try one thing, just type the IP of remote end.

`$ scp canserhan@embserv:~/tar_files/rtl_archive.tar serhan@<remote-ip>:~Documents`

Moreover, try giving full/absolute path instead of `~`.